# <iframe> will not display PDF file, just outline

Tags: iframe

here is my code:

```
<iframe data="pickone(1).pdf" type="application/pdf" id="p1_img"></iframe>
```

I am confused why this just shows a box and not the actual image

Comment: Are you sure the address is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Using an iframe to "render" a PDF will not work on all browsers; it depends on how the browser handles PDF files. Some browsers (such as Firefox and Chrome) have a built-in PDF rendered which allows them to display the PDF inline where as some older browsers. I found this link that may help.
http://pdfobject.com
You can also try this basic code, no promise these will work
`<iframe src="http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf" width="800px" height="600px" >`

Good Luck,
Rob